# ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am working on sftp outbound adapter with Spring Integration 4.3 release.

I am able to successfully send the file to sftp location but i want to update the database record to complete status.

I am looking ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice for an option but not able to figure it out how to call a method from setOnSuccessExpressionString.

Tried with below option.

```
@Bean 
public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice afterPut() {

    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    ///context.setBeanResolver((BeanResolver) new SftpPutBean());

    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    try {
        context.registerFunction("mymethod", SftpPutBean.class.getDeclaredMethod("mymethod", new Class[] { String.class }));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //String abc 

    String helloWorldReversed = parser.parseExpression("#mymethod(headers['transmissionId'])").getValue(advice, String.class);


    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("helloWorldReversed");
    advice.setPropagateEvaluationFailures(true);
    return advice;
}

public void mymethod(String id) { 
    try { 
        TransmissionQueue abc = transmissionQueueDataService.findById(Integer.parseInt(id)); 
        abc.setStatus("COMPLETED"); 
        transmissionQueueDataService.saveTransmissionQueue(abc); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your function with the Spring Integration evaluation context factory. [Instructions here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html#spel-functions).

> To provide a SpEL Function via Java Configuration, you should declare a SpelFunctionFactoryBean bean for each function. The sample above can be configured as follows:

```
@Bean
public SpelFunctionFactoryBean xpath() {
    return new SpelFunctionFactoryBean(XPathUtils.class, "evaluate");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gary... I did that and it is working fine now :)